# Why can't I share the clipboard using TightVNC server on Windows from Mac's screen sharing?

Tags: windows, macos, clipboard, tightvnc

I have the TightVNC server running on Windows 7 Home Edition and I'm using Screen Sharing on Mac OS X. On the Mac, the clipboard sharing button is greyed out:

[image]

If I copy and paste in either OS, the clipboard isn't transmitted. There appear to be no options in the TightVNC server configuration.

Any ideas how to get clipboard sharing to work?

**Edit:** Clipboard sharing works fine if I use the TightVNC *viewer* from a Windows machine. However, there's no TightVNC client for Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your VNC config process on the server may have crashed out or just never ran in the first place.

The command that might get you going again:

```
vncconfig &
```

http://rreddy.blogspot.com/2009/07/vncviewer-clipboard-operations-like.html

If you don't have access to the server you may need to get someone else to sort it out for you.

I understand the differences between VNC and RDP, and I realise the server may be distant or not yours in the first place.... but you would get more security and features by use Remote Desktop Protocol (Terminal Services) on the Windows box, then using Cord to connect to it from your Mac.

Comment: Okay so cord is a remote desktop client for mac, but the problem with connecting to a windows remote desktop server is the windows machine logs out. VNC is far less invasive it's unfortunate there are these ridiculous issues of clipboard not getting shared properly. My current solution is to go from mac with cord, to a windows machine that I don't mind getting logged out of, then from there,  with TightVNC  from that windows machine to the windows machine I want to connect to!

Comment: apparently cord is deprecated and ha a bug where it crashes when you move the window. , current thing is remote desktop for mac though you might need an apple id to download it

Comment: cord is deprecated and has a bug where it crashes when you move the window. , current thing is remote desktop for mac though you might need an apple id to download it   windows remote desktop for mac  (called microsoft remote desktop 10) is the thing to use   https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/microsoft-remote-desktop-10/id1295203466?mt=12   (and that works from a mac to a windows 7 machine no problem).   You can find the app in the app store free. It will log you out on the windows server  just as a remote desktop client on windows would..  hence i'm using a comptuier in the middle as described.

Comment: The problem with MS RDP client, to at least Windows Server 2012 R2, is that you can't login to the console session.  For code signing with EV certs, the software needs to be run from the console.  That's why some of us are forced to use non-RDP solutions and the lack of copy/paste is painful, but the cost of doing business.

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally TightVNC Server seems to end up with multiple processes.

- Check in task man - how may VNC Server processes are running on the server.
- If you can identify the real one, kill the others.
- If not - stop them all (you will need physical/KVM access to do this).
- Start them again.

It's possible that as TightVNC Server can run as an app or service, you may have the app in your startup and the service on auto, so two get started. You will need to remove one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The VNC solutions connecting between mac and windows don't seem to be much good when it comes to the clipboard. I don't know what client you used on MAC to connect to Windows TightVNC server.  I tried chicken of the VNC,(mac to windows)  and found the clipboard sharing to be poor e.g. seamless one way and not the other way.   And I tried TightVNC(windows to MAC - mac's native remote desktop server  allows tightvnc client/viewer to connect to it) and  found clipboard sharing not happening in the sense of working both ways.

There is an app developed by Microsoft for MAC, which is a remote desktop client for Mac. So that can let you connect Mac to Windows.  I haven't used it much but as far as I can tell you get proper clipboard sharing with that. You can find it in the app store. Microsoft remote desktop  10.  https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/microsoft-remote-desktop-10/id1295203466?mt=12   i'm connecting fine Mac to a Windows 7 machine with that.

Like with the windows remote desktop client, the windows server you connect to will log out(which I don't like, it's a bit invasive). So i'm currently going Mac (With MS remote desktop) to a Windows computer I don't mind automatically logging out from, and running TightVNC viewer from there, to a windows computer running TightVNC server.

Prior to MS remote desktop, people used 'cord' on mac, which was a remote desktop client for mac, but now MS have written one and it works better.  And Cord is now deprecated, has a bug where it crashes when a window is moved(which they fixed in code but have not bothered to fix in release), and it's no longer being developed.

It may be worth getting Windows Server instead of eg a regular windows version, and then you might not get logged out when you remote desktop in  https://serverfault.com/questions/55534/how-do-i-keep-an-account-always-logged-into-windows-but-allowing-other-sessions